# ext2fs and e2p packages are not found

Tags: linux, centos, grep, packages

I'm installing `ext4magic` on CentOS 7. When I run `./configure` it stops at a certain point returning an error message.

```
configure error: You must install the develop packages "ext2fs, blkid, e2p, uuid" to build ext4magic
```

I installed `e2fsprogs-devel` version 1.42.9 for CentOS 7.9 package and established to get `e2p` and `ext2fs` packages installed within the package

However when I run `rpm -qa | grep e2p` and `rpm -qa | grep ext2fs` I don't see the packages installed.

Is there any direct rpm to install those required packages?

Comment: Try running sudo apt full-upgrade or counter part on your OS  to renew packages and remove old ones and see if that helps.

Comment: `apt` is for Ubuntu I'm on CentOS and even when running `yum full-upgrade` on CentOS it didn't work

Comment: If that did work you may need to reinstall your OS

Comment: I'm on CentOS Rescue Mode. I'm sure there should be a solution

Answer (score 1):

`ext4magic`'s `configure` is a bit unintuitive (read: misleading) to follow. If you examine the check that generates the error you've shared, you'll see it checks for a series of `.h` files:

```
fail=0
AC_CHECK_HEADER([ext2fs/ext2fs.h],[],[fail=1])
AC_CHECK_HEADER([blkid/blkid.h],[],[fail=1])
AC_CHECK_HEADER([e2p/e2p.h],[],[fail=1])
AC_CHECK_HEADER([uuid/uuid.h],[],[fail=1])
test $fail = 1 &&
AC_MSG_ERROR([You must install the develop packages "ext2fs , blkid , e2p , uuid" to build ext4magic])
```

`ext2fs.h` and `e2p.h` are provided by the `e2fsprogs-devel` package you installed. `uuid.h` is provided by `libuuid`, which `systemd`, `yum` itself and a bunch of other packages depend on, so chances are you already have it. This (misleading) error message is caused by the missing `blkid.h` file, which is provided by `libblkid-devel`.

Once you resolve that, you'll encounter another error message prompting you to install `zlib-devel` and `bzip2-devel`, and then another instructing you to install `file-devel`.

In short, you'll need:

```
yum install gcc e2fsprogs-devel libblkid-devel zlib-devel bzip2-devel file-devel
```